# Document management with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, upload, download, document

Anybody can recommend a good library to use for:

1. Upload document (Office, PDFs and others)
2. Download document
3. Render Thumbnail and preview doc in the browser

It would be best to have all of the above but 1 and 2 is good too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) and [CarrierWave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) are two popular uploading libraries.

Downloading doesn't require anything special; use [send_file](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_file).

Not sure what the canonical Rails doc preview would be.

Comment: +1 for Paperclip, I guess it's the one solution advocated by Heroku hosting platform.

Comment: Any reaon why i would choose one over the other? After i load a file, is there a way to display a thumbnail of the file? For example, if it is an PDF show a PDF icon? Also, do you know of any package to review an office file in a browser?

Comment: @user663778 CarrierWave is getting all the love lately, but honestly, my usage of both has been generic enough that I don't know enough to have an opinion.